# $document vs document working differently in Angular App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I am confused on why `$document` is not working in my run function but `document` is.

This works:

```
.run(function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', checkConnection, false);
//more code below
```

This does not work:

```
.run(function($document, $rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
        $document.addEventListener('deviceready', checkConnection, false);
    //more code below
```

What am I missing here to use the angular `$document` service?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You wanted to attach DOM event to `document` object while registering event listener to it.

But `$document` does have that object on `0`th index & with its length, So you could easily get `document` from $document by doing `$document[0]`.

For making if more better using angular jQLite API you could use `.on`

```
$document.on('deviceready', checkConnection, false);
```